# What is the easiest way to publish a pub.dev package in a CI?

Tags: flutter, dart, continuous-integration

I'm trying to automatically publish a package in Github Actions using `dart pub publish` but for it I need to login. The login workflow needs user-interation (logging in via Google) and thus can't be used on a CI.

As per https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2227 there doesn't seem to be an easy way, but someone mentionned :

> Having to put the path like run: `echo ${{secrets.PUB_CREDENTIALS}} > /opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/1.9.1-hotfix.2-stable/x64/.pub-cache/credentials.json` is not really great to maintain.

Is the format of this `credentials.json` known ?

**Edit**: On Windows, `the credentials.json` file is not in `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\credentials.json` as indicated in the blog post, it is now at `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\dart\pub-credentials.json`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This medium post](https://birjuvachhani.medium.com/publish-your-flutter-dart-package-using-github-actions-99144cbf15ae) has a clear guide that could help you on publishing [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) or [Dart](https://dart.dev/) packages to [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) via **CI-CD** servers.

Assuming you have the following requirements:

> 1. A Flutter package ready to be published.
> 2. An active account on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/).
> 3. A repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/) with admin access.
> 4. A working laptop, internet connection, and some patience!

These are the steps to follow:

> 1. Retrieve Login Credentials for [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/)
> 2. Create Secrets on [GitHub](https://github.com/)
> 3. Write a shell script to set credentials
> 4. Create a workflow for **GitHub Action** to publish a package.
> 5. Triggering Builds.

Take note of this when running `pub publish`:

> When we run this command in our terminal for the first time, `pub`
> would ask us to log in to our [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) account by
> opening the **URL** printed on the command line. Once we log in using
> that URL, `pub` store some **login credentials** (which happens to be
> some tokens) into a file called `credentials.json`.
>
> Next time when you run `pub publish` command, it checks for this file
> and proceeds further without asking for login again. This gave me a
> hint that to make it work on **CI-CD servers**, we need to create this
> file somehow on the build machine.

You can visit the blog "[Publish Your Flutter/Dart Package using GitHub Actions](https://birju.dev/posts/publish-your-flutter-package-using-github-actions/)" for more details on each steps mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/automated-publishing

I cannot post an explanation here as stackoverflow rules would require because this is too long and might change in the future.